# movenext button not working in java

Tags: java, jdbc

```
 private void btn_nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{       
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connect =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:reimbursement");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    try 
    {

     stmt = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
     sql = "select * from reimbursementMaster";
     rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
     rs=stmt.getResultSet();
     if(rs.next())
     {
         empcode=rs.getString("EmployeeCode");
         empname=rs.getString("EmployeeName");
         loc=rs.getString("Location");
         location=loc;
      }
      else
      {
           rs.previous();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "End of File","Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE ); 
      }
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

}

Comment: To get an answer you should explain your problem with more detail.

Comment: with this little information i can only say that "debug your code" :p

Comment: As Mr bellabax said i'm getting only first result whenever i press next button please tell me where i've to write connection code instead inside the btn_nextActionPerformed()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess...
Your problem is you are getting only the first result all the times is because the resultset is reopened from scratch every time you press the next button.

1. declare `Resultset rs` as class member,
2. open `rs` out of `btn_nextActionPerformed()` (where you build the UI
   can be a good place) and `rs.next()` should work as expected.

Comment: I'm new to java and netbeans can you please tell me clearly where i've to open rs

Comment: IDK where netbeans create GUI: initComponents(), initGUI(), initializeComponents() or others are good candidates

Comment: I've changed my code as you suggest but now i'm getting an error that "Resultset closed"

Comment: Prepare a new question, post relevant code and describe your problem carefully; attach stacktrace of your error and wait for someone else answer your question. Otherwise try debug, it's really useful to learn! :)

Comment: I got the result :) :)